# Que signifie l'abréviation « Bin » ?

Tags: abréviations

J'ai récemment vu l'abréviation *F<sup>le</sup> B<sup>in</sup>* sur une pierre tombale du sud de la France. La première abréviation signifie *famille* j'imagine. Mais impossible de savoir le sens de la seconde.

Des idées ?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Il est très improbable que l'on ait abrégé un patronyme; il doit donc s'agir d'un prénom.

Les plus vraisemblables sont **B**enjam**in** suivi de **B**ernard**in** puis du beaucoup moins courant **B**audo**in**/**B**audou**in**.

Comment: Même un prénom je trouve ça curieux à abréger vu qu'il y a plein de possibilité. C'est une tombe du sud de la France j'ai oublié de préciser.

Comment: Il n'y a pas énormément de possibilités et sans doute aucune ambiguïté pour les visiteurs contemporains aux décès de l'intéressé. La commune et la date approximative du caveau permettraient peut-être de retrouver de qui il s'agit.

Comment: Mais si *F<sup>ll</sup>* veut dire *famille* alors il est étrange d’y trouver juste après un nom. Non ?

Comment: Le premier mot est F<sup>LE</sup>. Le E est un peu usé mais c'est bien un E.

Comment: @Fauve Pourquoi étrange ? Après Famille, on trouve toujours au moins un nom qui est parfois précédé d'un prénom, par exemple pour distinguer deux familles homonymes.